# How to print the information that Perl prints with "--version", but from within a script?

Tags: perl

To print the Perl version from within a script use `$^V`. But I would like to see the full string that Perl prints with `--version` or `-v`, which looks like

"This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread". Or "This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3) built for x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi (with 7 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)".

I have two environments that I think may be calling two different installations of Perl, but both are new so `$^V` is returning 5.24.1 for both.

Comment: Why not get even more detail by using [Config::myconfig](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config#myconfig())?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Because I didn't know it existed

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [Config](https://perldoc.pl/Config) module:

```
$ perl -MConfig -E 'say "perl $^V built for $Config{archname}"'
perl v5.26.1 built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

Comment: That's a core module so it looks like this is the answer, but I was specifically looking for a way to do it within a script, if you could rephrase it.

Comment: @felwithe `use Config; print "$Config{archname}\n";`,  `use Config (); while(my($k, $v) = each %Config::Config){print "$k\t$v\n"}`

Comment: @felwithe What do you mean? This answer is using `Config` within a script.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, but his code is from the command line. I already knew how to do it from the command line (just use -v). I was specifically asking how to do it from within a script.

Comment: @felwith, Yes, but the same code could used in a script (if preceded by `use Config; use feature qw( say );`). Shawn used to it in a command line so you could see the output, that's all.

Comment: Re "*That's a core module*", That's putting it mildly. It's a module that's built alongside with `perl`, containing information about the `perl` being built.

Comment: @melpomene It requires extra knowledge on the part of the user. At least several pieces. The user may not have those pieces of extra knowledge. That's why it has to actually answer the question as asked before I can accept it.

Comment: @felwithe What extra knowledge are you talking about? Also, why do you think `perl file-with-code` is a script but `perl -e inline-code` is not?

Comment: @felwithe, Re "*That's why it has to actually answer the question as asked before I can accept it.*", You can accept it as it. But it's your prerogative not to do so.

Comment: @melpomene, `-MConfig -E` instead of `use Config; use feature qw( say );`

Comment: @ikegami OK, true. But those are easily looked up in [`perldoc perlrun`](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-m%5B-%5Dmodule) and technically there's nothing that prevents you from doing e.g. `#!perl -MConfig` in a script file.

Comment: @melpomene Noone said it would be hard to translate, and that wouldn't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact string (as it's in `perl -v` output) in your script, then you can run the "perl -v" command from your script and get the string directly from the command output using the [IPC::Run::run()](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run).

```
use strict;

use IPC::Run qw(run);

# Variables to capture the STDOUT and STDERR
my ($out, $err);

# function "run" from IPC::Run to execute the "perl -v" command
# and keep the STDOUT in $out variable and STDERR in $err
# $out will have the complete output of "perl -v" command
run([$^X, "-v"], \undef, \$out, \$err);

# split the output at new line and
# then get the second line (index 1) from the array
my $version_line = ( split /\n/, $out )[1];

print $version_line."\n";
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/perl` is the absolute path on my system, btw thanks for updating the answer.

Comment: Sure, but the point is that it might not be for someone else. Or worse, it could be a different `perl` than the one being used if they have multiple builds of `perl` installed. By using `$^X`, you get the right one.